# Quick Map Service - Update Broke Quick Map Service

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-2.18, quickmapservices

I recently triggered an update of my Quick Map Service plugin.  The update I am trying to update to 0.19.10.1.  I have QGIS 2.18.19.  Once I ran the update, I received the following error:

```
Plugin Broken 
ImportError: cannot import name uic.
```

Comment: Try renaming (or deleting) your `.qgis2` user settings folder (location varies depending on operating system). Then reinstalling your plugins.